# Dialog pick function

Tags: android, android-activity

So I want to make a function like this:

```
private HashMap<> getpickedDate() {
//show Dialog with calender view
//where the uaer selects a date
//like date = new HashMap<>();
//date.put("day", daypicked);
return date;
}
```

Is that even possible?
 Ps: I am new to Android so I dont know mich about it.

Comment: Want to save the array of dates or, select a single day

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: Select a single day no hours just day year and month